# How to document a callback using DarkaOnLine / L5-Swagger in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swagger

I need to document a callback, I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
   /**
     * @OA\Post(
     *      path="/myurl-service",
     *      operationId="Id",
     *      tags={"Services"},
     *      summary="Summary",
     *      description="Desc",
     *      security={
     *           {"bearerAuth": {}}
     *       },
     *      @OA\RequestBody(
     *          required=true,
     *          @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/Request")
     *      ),
     *      callbacks={
     *          "Notification": {
     *              "{$request.body#/notification_url}":
     *              @OA\Post(
     *                  @OA\RequestBody(
     *                      required=true
     *                  ),
     *                  @OA\Response(
     *                      response=200,
     *                      description="Successful operation"
     *                  ),
     *              ),
     *          }
     *      }
     *     )
     */
```

Has anyone documented this and can give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON notation works.
Example:

```
     *        callbacks={
     *          "Notification"={
     *              "{$requestBody.notification_url}"={
     *                  "post"={
     *                      "requestBody"={
     *                          "required": true,
     *                          "content": {
     *                               "application/json": {
     *                                   "schema": {
     *                                       "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Schema"
     *                                   }
     *                               }
     *                           }
     *                      },
     *                      "responses"={
     *                          "200"={}
     *                      }
     *                  }
     *              }
     *          }
```